# Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Vector2[] to UnityEngine.Vector2

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have a line of code that looks like this

```c#
uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
```

It gave me the error Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Vector2[] to UnityEngine.Vector2

vertices is a Vertor3 and I tried putting the equation for vertices.Length but it still didn't work

Comment: What language is this? Where is the definition of Vector2 and Vertor3 [sic]?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins UnityEngine C# 2018.4 you should know what is Vector 2 and 3 is.

Comment: Maybe you should add one of the Unity tags like `unity3d-2dtools` to draw your question to the attention of people who know something about Unity. "compiler-errors" is a pretty broad category that probably nobody is explicitly watching.